Resetting Orika Debug Logging Levels
I am using Orika for a data conversion project. I would like to know how to drop the Debugging level down to ERROR (?) instead of DEBUG which it seems to be set to currently. The log files are huge and I'm sure the process time would change quite a bit too. Any help qould be much appreciated as I cannot find anything usefull on the net.
Many Thanks.
I've searched the internet as well as all documentation I could find but nothing provided a route to me solving my issue.

How can I debug Orika "set the “ma.glasnost.orika” package to DEBUG logging level.".   when you set it to ERROR debugging should stop

Thanks Luuk. I did see that on the Web but I don't know and can't exactly find where to change that setting. The documentation just mentions "set the logging level to DEBUG on the ma.glasnost.orika package". Is it in some config file I haven't found or do I need to do it at a class/method level whenever using the Orika Mapper ? In the same project I use JooQ which I can easily turn off using "Settings().withExecuteLogging(false)". I am lost with Orika though ???

The how to depends on the logging framework you use
for Log4j 2:
Adding or modifying the log4j2.xml configuration file:
<Configuration>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="ma.glasnost.orika" level="ERROR" />
        <!-- Other configurations -->
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>

for Log4j 1.x:
adding or modifying the log4j.properties file:
log4j.logger.ma.glasnost.orika=ERROR

